# Where should I check and unset the php CSRF token? in form control or in the index page?

Tags: php, security, token, csrf

I have a PHP login/register forms on the same page.
In this page I generate a CSRF token and expiry time and I put them in session variables.

I also post the token with the form.
in the **same** page, I check the form validity and if `POST['token']` is equal to `SESSION['token']`.

I also check for the token expiry. If everything is ok, I **header** the user to **index.php** and just before the header, I unset both the session token and session expiry.

In index.php I only check for `SESSION['loggedin']` and `SESSION['user_type']`, if not set and correct, then header to main page.

The question is, what is more secure? to check and unset the CSRF token and expiry in the form control "same page as the sign in form", or in index.php (where the user is redirected after being authenticated" ?

Comment: First one is the right way...

Comment: @pk_ thanks, is there a specific reason why? .. and is it secure enough to only check for session['loggedin'] "inside an if statement" in the index page "where only authenticated users should access" ? ..